# issue regarding Error code 302 for NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, http, http-status-code-302

I am currenting developing an NodeJS web application and I am trying to access it with other network FYI my IP is static. but when I am trying to access by company network, I am seeing error 302 FYI I can only see login page but cannot get data from my server but other than this network I can access my application also using HTTP, Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: 302 is not an error, and if you get a login page while accessing your server that sounds like a good thing. Are you not expecting a login page? Do you have any real error messages? Try to describe what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: In login page i have two field user and project